# Checking which of SQL conditions was met

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm looking for a more efficient way to debug my SQL queries, i'm using phpMyAdmin for most query checks. Here's an example of a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE
(
    `start` = {$start} OR
    ((`start` + (`runtime` * 60)) > {$start} AND (`start` + (`runtime` * 60)) <= {$end}) OR
    (`start` > {$start} AND `start` < {$end}) 
) AND `group_id` = {$group}
```

Now considering that $start and `start` are both timestamps it gets annoying when trying to see which of the conditions was met(and confusing), sometimes these conditions can be in large numbers(and not 3 like in the example), is there a way to quickly determine which one of them was met? Without manually removing each one of them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not a beautiful solution, but you can add each condition to the list of columns:

```
SELECT *,
    IF (`start` = {$start}, 1, 0) AS con1,
    IF (((`start` + (`runtime` * 60)) > {$start} AND (`start` + (`runtime` * 60)) <= {$end}), 1, 0) AS con2,
FROM `schedule` WHERE
(
`start` = {$start} OR
((`start` + (`runtime` * 60)) > {$start} AND (`start` + (`runtime` * 60)) <= {$end}) OR
(`start` > {$start} AND `start` < {$end}) 
) AND `group_id` = {$group}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put boolean expressions in the select-list, and give them meaningful column names. These expressions will be evaluated only for rows that satisfy the WHERE clause conditions, so it's not significantly extra work. These expressions return either 1 (true) or 0 (false) in the query result set.

```
SELECT ...,
  `start` = {$start} AS is_start,
  ((`start`+(runtime*60)) > {$start} AND (`start`+(runtime*60)) <= {$end}) AS is_overlapping,
  (`start` > {$start} AND `start` < {$end}) AS is_between_start_and_end
FROM `schedule` 
WHERE
(
  `start` = {$start} 
  OR ((`start`+(runtime*60)) > {$start} AND (`start`+(runtime*60)) <= {$end}) 
  OR (`start` > {$start} AND `start` < {$end}) 
) AND group_id = {$group}
```